# Рисование на C++

Tags: c++

При самостоятельном изучении C++ столкнулся с задачками, где надо нарисовать круг, линии, и т.д. Использую Dev-C++, ничего не получается, помогите.

Comment: А где надо рисовать: в консоли или в окне, на Windows или на Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Смотря где рисовать. Например рисовать "в файл" - тогда хорошо подходят библиотека [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). 
Если же хочется рисовать в окне, то тут к примеру нужно изучать winapi (если это под винды)  - гуглим по словам "winapi gdi", а также никто не отменял [gtk](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html)/[kde (qt)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/painting-basicdrawing.html).
Можно рисовать, используя DirectX/OpenGl...
В целом, вариантов очень много. Если хочется более точных туториалов, то решитесь -  какая именно техника вам нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать Borland C++. Там много всяких возможностей для рисование и достаточно всё просто.